# Edge file download notification "From:" flag is empty

Tags: javascript, html, blob, microsoft-edge

I am trying to use navigator.msSaveBlob to download file from blob object. I have special code for handle this in IE and Edge browser as below;

```
if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
}
```

But in the notification panel it is showing as below;

[image]

This code is working fine in IE and it correctly showing From as my sites domain name.

Does anyone know which settings I need to set to make this work in Edge. I am testing this in Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0 with Windows 10

Comment: the fact is, you are saving a Blob, so the url is technically correct

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your comment. I couldn't find any wrong with my blob or application url. So what might be the issue?

Comment: I never said there was something wrong with your blob ... I said your code is asking a user to save a blob, so why would `from` be a web site? that would be misleading

Comment: Yes @JaromandaX In IE it correctly showing my website name as From: Do you have any suggestion how we can add that information to navigator.msSaveBlob to work it in Edge?

Comment: no, because Edge is correct as far as I'm concerned

Answer (score 0):

Once I updated EDGE version to "Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0" it resolve this issue. Now it is correctly showing my domain name as "From:" in edge download notification.